# How can I parse a value that appears some place in a file using C#

Tags: c#

I have **strings** and each contain a value of RowKey stored like this:

```
data-RowKey=029
```

This occurs only once in each file. Is there some way I can get the number out with a C# function or do I have to write some kind of select myself.  I have a team mate who suggested linq but I'm not sure if this even works on strings and I don't know how I could use this.

**Update:**

Sorry I changed this from file to string.

Comment: do you know what like that value is always going to be on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it only exists once in a file, i would even throw an exception otherwise:

```
String rowKey = null;
try
{
    rowKey = File.ReadLines(path)
                .Where(l => l.IndexOf("data-RowKey=") > -1)
                .Select(l => l.Substring(12 + l.IndexOf("data-RowKey=")))
                .Single();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException) {
    // you might want to log this exception instead
    throw;
}
```

**Edit**: The simple approach with a string, take the first occurence which is always of length 3:

```
rowKey = text.Substring(12 + text.IndexOf("data-RowKey="), 3);
```

Comment: How could I do this if it was in a string and not a file?

Answer (score 2):

Linq does not really help you here. Use a regular expression to extract the number:

```
data-Rowkey=(\d+)
```

**Update:**

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"data-Rowkey=(\d+)");

string abc =  //;
Match match = r.Match(abc);
if (match.Success) 
{
  string rowKey = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

**Code:**

```
public string ExtractRowKey(string filePath)
{
  Regex r = new Regex(@"data-Rowkey=(\d+)");

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
  {
    string line; 
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      Match match = r.Match(line);
      if (match.Success) return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Stefan can you tell me how I could do this if it's just in a string variable? For example string abc = ".........."; is the source.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex g = new Regex(@"data-RowKey=(?<Value>\d+)");

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("myFile.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Match m = g.Match(line);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            string v = m.Groups["Value"].Value;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is not in a file and just in a variable. How could I do this?

Comment: string myVar = "<blah>"; Match m = g.Match(myVar); if (m.Succes) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming following

1. File must contain data-Row (with exact match including case)
2. Number length is 3

Following is the code snippet

```
        var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("rootDirPath");

        var tuples = new List<Tuple<String, int>>();
        foreach(String fileName in fileNames)
        {
            String fileData =File.ReadAllText(fileName) ;
            int index = fileData.IndexOf("data-RowKey=");
            if(index >=0)
            {
                String numberStr = fileData.Substring(index+12,3);// ASSUMING data-RowKey is always found, and number length is always 3
                int number = 0;
                int.TryParse(numberStr, out number);
                tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(fileName, number));
            }
        }
```